# How to Cast Date to String for Chart with Weekly Groupings in MS Access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, casting

I have a simple Access application where I want a chart that shows groupings by weeks from daily records.

I have a query that converts the groups by the week and then displays the week as the first day like this:

WeekBegin: DateAdd("d",-(DatePart("w",[ScoreDate])-1),[ScoreDate])

Thsi gives the Sunday beginning the week correctly. The problem comes when I go to make a chart. The chart Row Source is

SELECT [WeekBegin],Sum([Scores]), (etc...) FROM [query]   GROUP BY [WeekBegin];

When I do this the chart treats the bottom axis as a date value and each week is seven days apart making the bars tiny.

[image: graph with tiny bars in date format]

I'm sure the date format is the issue because when I make an integer out of the week value it formats how I want:

[image: Graph with bars how I want them]

I can't figure out how to get it to show as a date like "mm/dd" but not treat it as a date and add all those blank days in between. I've tried messing with the axis settings but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: As far as I know, this is a known bug not yet corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the date as a varchar... use convert to get into whatever display format you want.

Comment: convert doesn't seem to work within Access. Ive tried using Format which returns a varchar but the chart still interprets it as a date.